# How to make a hour countdown timer with jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to know how to make a countdown timer with a jQuery plugin from here http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

I need a countdown timer of 2 hours.
This is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.2.0/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.2/jquery.countdown.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p>hi</p>
    <div id="getting-started"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#getting-started').countdown('2020/10/10', function(event) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is exactly your question? Do you get any errors or what? You code seems to work fine(just not sure about 2 hours countdown when you have set the year to 2020!)

Comment: I want a 2 hour countdown timer that one works but counts from 2020/10/10

Comment: OK, got it, please check my answer to see if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to show a count down with 2 hours, then you have to get current date-time and add it by 2 hours then set the countdown.

With this line you can get the current date of the client:
`var today = new Date();`

And then with this line you can create a new variable with desired new date in it(as for you next 2 hours):

`var newDate = today.setHours(today.getHours() + 2)`

And finally you can replace `'2020/10/10'` in your code with this newly created date variable `newDate`

Your code with a little change will be like this:

```js
var param = 2; // Change this if you want more or les than 2 hours

var today = new Date();
var newDate = today.setHours(today.getHours() + param);

$('#getting-started').countdown(newDate, function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.2/jquery.countdown.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.2.0/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<p>hi</p>
<div id="getting-started"></div>
```